# Is there a formula for calculating the overhead of a Docker container?

Tags: docker

Supposed I want to run several Docker containers at the same time.

Is there any formula I can use to find out in advance on how many containers can be run at the same time by a single Docker host? I.e., how much CPU, memory & co. do I have to take into account for the containers themselves?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not a formula per se, but you can gather information about resource usage in the container by examining Linux control groups in `/sys/fs/cgroup`.

### Links

See [this excellent post](http://blog.docker.io/2013/10/gathering-lxc-docker-containers-metrics/) by Jérôme Petazzoni of Docker, Inc on the subject.

See also Google's [cAdvisor tool](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) to view container resource usage.

[This IBM research paper](http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/0929052195DD819C85257D2300681E7B/$File/rc25482.pdf) documents that Docker performance is higher than KVM in every measurement.

Comment: What's the paper name please? The link is broken and I would really like to take a look at that paper :-)

Comment: Oops, it's not a broken link. Starbucks internet died in the middle of loading :-P For future travellers, the title is "An Updated Performance Comparison of Virtual Machines and Linux Containers by Felter et al."

Comment: [What about this paper](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1252694/FULLTEXT01.pdf) ?

Answer (score 3):

`docker stats` is also useful for getting a rough idea for how CPU and Memory your containers use.

Answer (score 0):

cAdvisor is going to provide resource usage and other interesting stats about all containers o a host. We have a preliminary setup for root usage, but we are adding a lot more this week.