# Performance Comparison between Native System and Docker Container

Tags: performance, docker

Generally speaking, how much faster is native system compared to docker container ?

Comment: I can't put a hand on the two links I'm looking for. Q/A on SO actually! One reported a container faster for the same C source-code than the host itself. The gcc version was just newer. Another asked about disk access, I cannot find this answer neither (even though I answered it myself) and there is no difference neither.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the runtime performance cost of a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889053/what-is-the-runtime-performance-cost-of-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 4):

Docker induces no significant overhead on CPU nor memory usage,  compared to a native execution (worse observation: -4%; 0% on all others)

Ref:http://blog.pierreroudier.net/2015/08/docker-vs-kvm-vs-native-performance-comparison/