# Resources required for running application on server VS running application in LXC container?

Tags: java, docker, lxc, openvz, lxd

[LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/getting-started/)/[LXD](https://stgraber.org/2015/04/21/lxd-getting-started/) offers a virtual machines like [openVZ](https://openvz.org/Main_Page) but removes the overhead of having custom kernel installation on GUEST systems.

> What will be overhead on the GUEST operating system for running
>   application server like JETTY/TOMCAT in a LXC container VS running the
>   the same application server directly on the GUEST operating system ?

First one I noticed is the size of the container itself which is around 300 MB with tomcat server installed and [tomcat server](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi) itself was only 10 MB.

Initial findings are not comprehensive either

- https://superuser.com/questions/871724/whats-the-minimum-overhead-of-a-linux-container/895490
- [What is the runtime performance cost of a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889053/what-is-the-runtime-performance-cost-of-a-docker-container) (this is comparison with docker)

Answer (score 0):

A container for any software can have a much different size

- if it is based on Ubuntu, Debian, a Debian light like Bitnami, Alpine or Busybox
- if you install a software with all the recommended and suggested packages or not, see this excellent article from Dave Beckett's blog

https://www.dajobe.org/blog/2015/04/18/making-debian-docker-images-smaller/

- if you use tools like docker-slim

https://github.com/docker-slim/docker-slim

or strip-docker-image

https://github.com/mvanholsteijn/strip-docker-image

to reduce the size of the image

- if you use docker version 1.13, you have tools to reduce the number of layers using docker squash

https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/22641

Some examples,

1) the popular grafana-xxl has a size of 357.3 MB

while the same image using docker-slim has a size of 18.73 MB

https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/grafana-xxl.slim/

2) netcat

based on Debian (159,3 MB)

based on Alpine (size 7,812 MB)

https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/netcat_alpine/

(and about 2 or 3 MB based on Busybox)

Comment: my question is specific to LXD  and not docker :(, thanks for the reply though