# Multiple Docker Container Performance

Tags: linux, docker, containers

Let's say I had a bunch of various docker containers that all were based off python3.5.  Would the task of running all the containers (let's say either 5, 10, or 20 containers) as daemons at the same time use any more/less resources than just running all the tasks as daemons natively with python3.5 on the Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 1):

docker has very little overhead by design (especially under linux), also see this SO article [What is the runtime performance cost of a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889053/what-is-the-runtime-performance-cost-of-a-docker-container)

so the choice for or against docker should be based on your requirements, not on performance considerations.

Comment: There are no requirements. More just a theoretical question. Like what if I had a powerful workstation that was running 10-20 docker containers that use the Ubuntu container as their base image?

Comment: i'd use this https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/ unless you really need ubuntu for some reason. and theoretically this is difficult to answer, 10-20 dockers doing nothing will not use much ressources. if you want to build a microservice architecture based on that i would say that is entirely feasible.