# Docker container performance degredation

Tags: performance, docker, kaldi

I am running a very resource intensive application (Kaldi audio transcription) within a Docker container. When comparing with running the same application natively on the host machine, performance is 2 - 3 X worse.

Could anyone shed some light on what might cause this ? I am not sure what would be a good place to start investigating.

Comment: Which docker image are you using ? What is your host machine (OS, hardware) ?

Comment: A similar question is this: [What is the runtime performance cost of a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889053/what-is-the-runtime-performance-cost-of-a-docker-container).

Answer (score 0):

The good place to start investigation is actually perf tool, not stackoverflow like described [here](https://hackernoon.com/another-reason-why-your-docker-containers-may-be-slow-d37207dec27f).

Most likely it is due to the some sort of memory limitations. Kaldi decoding eats a lot of memory.