# How large can (should) a docker container get?

Tags: database, docker, scalability

I have Docker container that provisions a version of Postgress with extensions and such. I use this for development purposes and the spin-up requires a whole import of a previous SQL dump.

I'd like to be able to run Postgres instances in production inside Docker containers (Docker alone, not Kubernetes) so I can spin them up without manually provisioning.

**Assuming I have a very large box (i.e. `x1.32xlarge` on AWS), how okay is it for me to be running an equally large DB instance inside of a docker container on this box?**

Answer (score 0):

You are more likely in need to read this question

[What is the runtime performance cost of a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889053/what-is-the-runtime-performance-cost-of-a-docker-container)

Storage size is different (cheaper) thing than performance so it does not matter here.

Production databases are running in contenerized environment so why not? Just ensure you secure that properly

Do some research as I am not sure if you understand how docker works internally, I suspect you think about docker as virtualization layer while its not.