# Container vs Host (Native) Performance

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-ecs

- Since containers are lightweight os virtualization, can we get the same performance as native (host)?
- What would be the difference in performance?

Any leads are highly appreciated or if you have any analysis reports or any reference with host vs containers performance comparison will help.

IA

Answer (score 6):

This question has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889053/what-is-the-runtime-performance-cost-of-a-docker-container). While the answer is specifically referring to Docker, it can be generalized to other
OCI compliant Container technologies: they all use the same primitives such as cgroups, Linux namespaces and (mostly) unionfs.

Keep in mind, that (in case of Docker) this only refers to containers running in Linux. If you operate Docker containers on Windows or Mac you have a LInux virtualization layer which causes extra (significant1) performance loss.

Edit: there are other approaches of "containerization" like KVM - as the question is tagged with "Docker" I assume it is specifically asking for the performance impact of docker containers.

Comment: Thanks, apprecite it