# Are there any downsides to using Conda inside Docker?

Tags: python, docker, conda, miniconda

If I use Conda to manage my Python environment and packages, and want to replicate that in Docker, I can use Conda inside Docker. The continuumio/miniconda3 Docker image is about 400MB larger than Python-slim, but other than that, are there any real-world downsides/performance issues in running Conda inside Docker? (As opposed to installing packages in Docker via pip, Pipenv, etc.?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the runtime performance cost of a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889053/what-is-the-runtime-performance-cost-of-a-docker-container)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt -- No, my question is if the combination of Conda + Docker has a performance cost.

Comment: State-of-the-art for Conda + Docker is [the `micromamba-docker` image](https://micromamba-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which supports an `alpine` fundamental image (i.e., thin). With proper cleanup of package cache, the overhead of Micromamba is ~15MB, with the advantage of precompiled everything (copy-only installs) and covering non-Python requirements (no extra `apt-get`, `yum`, etc.). If the question is about performance, then a test should be proposed - otherwise this is not a concrete problem.

Answer (score 2):

In general that works fine. It depends on what your goals are.

If you want to have a lean Python service container, you could use the official Python image from docker hub tagged with `alpine`, e.g. `python3.12-alpine` tag. Then use `pip` to install from `requirements.txt` or a Poetry-based project setup.

This will get you an even smaller image size than `slim` and typically work just as well.

However, if you want to replicate your Conda experience 1:1 your approach with Conda in Docker has its reasons: Conda binaries are built differently than regular Python wheels, e.g. it has its own version of Openblas, etc. with different optimizations.

Comment: Right, but is there a performance hit for using Conda in Docker? (As opposed to using Pip, Poetry, Pipenv, etc.)

Comment: There is no performance hit by using Conda, with or without Docker. Performance is different due to shipped binaries, as mentioned.